# How to properly use Timespan() constructor in C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I am developing a stopwatch for Windows Phone 8, but actually I am not able to get the timing thing properly. I want to update the second after every 1000 milliseconds, but since I am new to C#, I am not able to get it right. This is the code I have right now. :/

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Milli_Stopwatch;
using System.Windows.Threading;


namespace Milli_Stopwatch
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        int millisec = 00;
        int sec = 00;
        int min = 00;
        int hour = 00;

        Boolean check = false;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,1);
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(DispatcherTimer_tick);

        }

        private void DispatcherTimer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            if (millisec == 1000) 
                { 
                    millisec = 00; 
                    sec = sec + 1; 
                    Secblock.Text = sec.ToString(); 
            }

            if (sec == 59)
            {
                sec = 00;
                min = min + 1;
                Minblock.Text = min.ToString();
            }

            if (min == 59)
            {
                min = 00;
                hour = hour + 1;
                Hourblock.Text = hour.ToString();
            } 

            millisec = millisec + 1;
            Millisecblock.Text = millisec.ToString();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (check == false)
            {
                timer.Start();
                check = true;
                startbutton.Content = "STOP";
            }
            else {
                timer.Stop();
                check = false;
                startbutton.Content = "START";
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            check = false;
            startbutton.Content = "START";
            millisec = 000;
            sec = 00;
            min = 00;
            hour = 00;

            Millisecblock.Text = "00";
            Secblock.Text = "00";
            Minblock.Text = "00";
            Hourblock.Text = "00";

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: no need to write one, you have one here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328522/Stop-Watch-application-for-Windows-Phone-7

Comment: @HansPassant i agree with you, I will rectify this problem, but DispatcherTimer_tick is not updating the sec properly. It almost takes 10 sec for millisec to reach 1000 and then the sec gets updated. What should i do for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Clocks go to the next minute when the second reaches 60, not 59.  Same for minutes to hour.  You got it kinda right for milliseconds, but then messed it up by incrementing it afterwards.

You should not do this anyway, a timer isn't accurate enough and you'll always fall behind.  Store the value of DateTime.UtcNow when you start.  Subtract that from DateTime.UtcNow when the timer ticks.  Now you have an accurate TimeSpan that always matches the elapsed wall clock time and is not affected by the timer accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are initializing the timespan to 1 ms. IMHO, it is much easier to just use `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);` instead of the constructor.

Second of all, you can not rely on the timer elapsed events to happen exactly when you schedule them to happen, so for your stop watch to be correct, you need to be using something like `DateTime.Now - {the DateTime.Now from when you started the timer}` and parsing it.

```
DateTime startedTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
```

Then when you handle the elapsed event.

```
txtTime.Text = (DateTime.Now - startedTimeStamp).ToString("G");
```

No need to handle each scenario for hour, minute, second, ms etc... or any of that. The framework will handle it for you.